# Location of "Documentation for Android SDK"

Tags: android

Where is the exact location of the "Documentation for Android SDK" in windows? I downloaded the independent "docs-23_r01.zip" file cause Android Studio takes hours to download and install it. But I couldn't figure out where to put the extracted folder so that i could be able to use it in Android Studio. For example last time I downloaded the google USB driver and put it in the "Sdk\extras\google" folder. So please help me out. Thanks!

Comment: Put the zip file in Android sdk's **temp** directory -> Start SDK Manager -> Select the same component from the list and click Install Package.

Comment: As far as I know, it seems to be located at sdk\docs\

Comment: Thanks, it worked in the sdk\docs\